# Button press event - event handling and picking: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary, boolean

I have the following command below.

The overall aim is to allow the user to **select a Y-value** by pressing on the bar graph. The **colour of each bar** should then **change** depending on what this Y-value is.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame({"values":[np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650).mean(), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650).mean(), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650).mean(), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650).mean()], 
                  "index":[1992,1993,1994,1995]})

standarderrors1992 = stats.sem(np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650))
standarderrors1993 = stats.sem(np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650))
standarderrors1994 = stats.sem(np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650))
standarderrors1995 = stats.sem(np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)) 
add1992 = 1.96*standarderrors1992
add1993 = 1.96*standarderrors1993
add1994 = 1.96*standarderrors1994 
add1995 = 1.96*standarderrors1995
mean1992 = np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650).mean()
mean1993 = np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650).mean()
mean1994 = np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650).mean()
mean1995 = np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650).mean()
labels = [1992,1993,1994,1995]
add = [add1992,add1992,add1994,add1995]
```

1. This first part organises the **raw data**.

```
def onclick(event):
    plt.cla()
    plt.bar(df["index"].values,df["values"].values,align='center', alpha=0.5,yerr=add)
    plt.xticks(labels)
    plt.show()
    limit = event.ydata
    limits = []
    limits.append(limit)
    if len(limits) >= 1:
        plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_disconnect(plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick))
    dict = {mean1992:add1992,mean1993:add1993,mean1994:add1994,mean1995:add1995}
    colourofbars = [] 
    for key,value in dict.items():
        if limits[0] > (key+(value)):
            colour = 1 
            colourofbars.append(colour)
        elif limits[0] < (key-(value)):
            colour = 0 
            colourofbars.append(colour)
        elif (limits[0] < (key+(value))) and (limits[0] > (key-(value))): 
            colour = ((key+(value))-limits[0])/((key+value)-(key-value)) 
            colourofbars.append(colour)
    df["colourofbars"] = colourofbars
    cmap = plt.cm.rainbow
    norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(df["colourofbars"].values),vmax=max(df["colourofbars"].values))
    plt.bar(df["index"].values,df["values"].values,color=cmap(norm(df["colourofbars"].values)),align='center', alpha=0.5,yerr=add)
    plt.xticks(labels)
    plt.axhline(y=limits[0],linewidth=1, color='k')
    plt.title('Graph showing proportion of confidence interval lying above the threshold value',y=1.05)
    plt.ylabel('Possible Y-threshold values',labelpad=5)
    plt.xlabel('Year',labelpad=5)
    sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    plt.gcf().colorbar(sm)

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

2. Here, the user presses on the graph to select a value, which is then assigned to the list **'limits'**. The values in the list 'colourofbars' are appended accordingly.
3. Next, a **different colour** is assigned to each bar in the bar chart depending on the values in the **column 'colourofbars'**, after converting the list to a column in the dataframe **'df'**. I then try to plot a legend showing this colour gradient scale.

*However,* I keep getting the error: **IndexError: list index out of range**. Could anyone give me a helping hand as to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the function onclick() by removing these lines and placing them outside the function:

```
plt.cla()
plt.bar(df["index"].values,df["values"].values,align='center', alpha=0.5,yerr=add)
plt.xticks(labels)
plt.show()
```

Thus, the correct code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame({"values":[np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650).mean(), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650).mean(), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650).mean(), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650).mean()], 
                  "index":[1992,1993,1994,1995]})

standarderrors1992 = stats.sem(np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650))
standarderrors1993 = stats.sem(np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650))
standarderrors1994 = stats.sem(np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650))
standarderrors1995 = stats.sem(np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)) 
add1992 = 1.96*standarderrors1992
add1993 = 1.96*standarderrors1993
add1994 = 1.96*standarderrors1994 
add1995 = 1.96*standarderrors1995
mean1992 = np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650).mean()
mean1993 = np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650).mean()
mean1994 = np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650).mean()
mean1995 = np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650).mean()
labels = [1992,1993,1994,1995]
add = [add1992,add1992,add1994,add1995]
plt.cla()
plt.bar(df["index"].values,df["values"].values,align='center', alpha=0.5,yerr=add)
plt.xticks(labels)
plt.show()

def onclick(event):
    limit = event.ydata
    limits = []
    limits.append(limit)
    if len(limits) >= 1:
        plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_disconnect(plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick))
    dict = {mean1992:add1992,mean1993:add1993,mean1994:add1994,mean1995:add1995}
    colourofbars = [] 
    for key,value in dict.items():
        if limits[0] > (key+(value)):
            colour = 1 
            colourofbars.append(colour)
        elif limits[0] < (key-(value)):
            colour = 0 
            colourofbars.append(colour)
        elif (limits[0] < (key+(value))) and (limits[0] > (key-(value))): 
            colour = ((key+(value))-limits[0])/((key+value)-(key-value)) 
            colourofbars.append(colour)
    df["colourofbars"] = colourofbars
    cmap = plt.cm.rainbow
    norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=min(df["colourofbars"].values),vmax=max(df["colourofbars"].values))
    plt.bar(df["index"].values,df["values"].values,color=cmap(norm(df["colourofbars"].values)),align='center', alpha=0.5,yerr=add)
    plt.xticks(labels)
    plt.axhline(y=limits[0],linewidth=1, color='k')
    plt.title('Graph showing proportion of confidence interval lying above the threshold value',pad=5)
    plt.ylabel('Possible Y-threshold values',labelpad=5)
    plt.xlabel('Year',labelpad=5)
    sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    plt.gcf().colorbar(sm)

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

I am no longer getting the above error message. When I run this code, this figure appears:

[image]

When I then click on this graph, the correct output appears:

[image]